# Console program doesn't work occasionally?

Tags: c++, linux

Occasionally, usually right after I compile a program and run it, the values my console prints out are wrong. The odd thing is, even though I don't change anything to the code, after I compile and run it again, it works fine. This happens for all of my programs. Each one takes in a user input and prints out a line after manipulating some data using the input. This only happens on occasion when I first compile a program. It wouldn't normally be a huge problem but I'm entering my program for a local competition and I can't have it malfunctioning when they run it. Anyone know why this might be happening and how I can fix it?

Using Codeblocks 8.02 with GCC. Running Linux Mint 9 64-bit if it matters at all.

Comment: We need to see code if we're to give you any useful advice.

Comment: You haven't really begun to provide any information that could be used to answer this.  What type of errors?  Are there multiple source files?  Have you edited any of the files?  Are you building with a makefile or the IDE's own builder?   Does it also happen if you build some other way?  Does it happen if you clean the project?  Next time you get a bad executable save a snapshot of it and all the object files.  Then rebuild and diff the old and new objects (or objdumps thereof) or even just look at the timestamps.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a memory management issue (i.e. using memory after it's been freed, using an array outside of its bounds, etc.). We really need to see the code if we're to do more than guess...

Comment: Are you getting any warnings when you compile? Make sure you're compiling with -Wall on.

Comment: In MSVC it happens when the not all project dependences are set.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me also. When coding in C. But I was using MS Visual Studio. There in the solution I selected to clean the solution, so that any temp files of previous versions will go off.

But to provide a clear answer please upload your coding here. Because it is not clear what's your problem is. Good Luck